# dynamic object is changed when I modify another object VUE

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is the example of my problem:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#mainCreate',
  data: {
    v_total : 0,
    test : [],
  },
});
function f_test(){
  var d = [
    {title : 'p1', price : 0},
    {title : 'p2', price : 2},
    {title : 'p3', price : 0},
    {title : 'p4', price : 4}
  ]

  $.each(d, function(index,date){
    Vue.set(app.test, index, date);
  });
}

function changeV(){
 app.v_total += 10;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="mainCreate">
  <h4>I input the charge with a check according to a v-if, but look what happens if I select an input that was not checked and change the value of v_total .... reload the input</h4>

  v_total = {{ v_total}}
  <br>
    <span v-for="date in test">
      {{ date.title }}
      <input type="checkbox"
             name="featuresBox"
             v-bind:checked="date.price == 0">
      <br>
    </span>

    <button onClick="f_test()">create object</button>
    <button onClick="changeV()">change app.v_total</button>
</div>
```

if I just change the `app.v_total` because the input loses its `check` that I put with `v-if`? (I think it's because VUE believes that the test is also updated) and it should not be that way.

Comment: Add more code, show the part where you do `app.v_total = value`.

Comment: does not affect where I am changing the value to 'app.v_total', if I do it from the console it also happens the same, does it have any event to prevent the objects from being updated?

Comment: The behavior you are telling is not normal, something else must be reseting the `feature` data. Maybe those `readyIcheck()` or `calculateTotal.eventIcheck();`. Show their code or comment them and test.

Comment: It's not that either, it's VUE, I do not know if it's because 'app.features' added data dynamically, but that's it, when I'm molding another object, the 'app.features' takes it as if it had changed

Comment: Please see the help section on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't reproduce the described issue based on the limited information you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/m7g1uwL7/

Comment: Please notice that you sometimes say `.feature` and sometimes say `.features`. Which one is it?!

Comment: edited at the end add a short example of my problemhttps://jsfiddle.net/m7g1uwL7/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check a checkbox, you are "losing state" because nothing changes to the `data.price` of each checkbox, see:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#mainCreate',
  data: {
    v_total : 0,
    test : [],
  },
});
function f_test(){
  var d = [
    {title : 'p1', price : 0},
    {title : 'p2', price : 2},
    {title : 'p3', price : 0},
    {title : 'p4', price : 4}
  ]

  $.each(d, function(index,date){
    Vue.set(app.test, index, date);
  });
}

function changeV(){
 app.v_total += 10;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="mainCreate">
  v_total = {{ v_total}}
  <br>
    <span v-for="date in test">
      {{ date.title }}
      <input type="checkbox"
             name="featuresBox"
             v-bind:checked="date.price == 0"> date.price: {{ date.price }} - will not change when you mark the checkbox
      <br>
    </span>

    <button onClick="f_test()">create object</button>
    <button onClick="changeV()">change app.v_total</button>
</div>
```

When you change `v_total` it **seems** to reset the checkboxes because the change causes a re-render of the whole component.

It just resets the display of the checkboxes, it does not reset the values of the checkboxes, simply because their underlying data never changed.

**Solution/Workaround:** Add something to **really** change the `data.prince` when the checkboxes are checked, such as some code that executed on the `change` event, like:

```html
<input ... v-on:change="date.price = (date.price ? 0 : 1)">
```

Fixed demo below.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#mainCreate',
  data: {
    v_total : 0,
    test : [],
  },
});
function f_test(){
  var d = [
    {title : 'p1', price : 0},
    {title : 'p2', price : 2},
    {title : 'p3', price : 0},
    {title : 'p4', price : 4}
  ]

  $.each(d, function(index,date){
    Vue.set(app.test, index, date);
  });
}

function changeV(){
 app.v_total += 10;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="mainCreate">
  v_total = {{ v_total}}
  <br>
    <span v-for="date in test">
      {{ date.title }}
      <input type="checkbox"
             name="featuresBox"
             v-on:change="date.price = (date.price ? 0 : 1)"
             v-bind:checked="date.price == 0"> date.price: {{ date.price }}
      <br>
    </span>

    <button onClick="f_test()">create object</button>
    <button onClick="changeV()">change app.v_total</button>
</div>
```

**Note:** I understand the snippet you gave is just a part of something bigger, but you really shouldn't mix jQuery and Vue. You should do all that changing inside the methods of a Vue instance. This will be much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: thanks, it is a solution to my problem, but I still have the doubt of whether every object that is modified by VUE, renders the other objects. that is a problem

Comment: It does. That's what's Vue is all about.